# How to find a trend in a sequence in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, loops

I have an accessibility vector with 1's and 0's. 1 means the weather is good; and 0 meaning the weather is not good and the place is not accessible.

I have a step_duration of (e.g.) 10 hrs. Considering the step_index (start of the step) as 101,I need to find a window of straight 10 hrs of good weather.

Expected solution: With 10 hours of expected weather, say the accessibility vector is [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] . So, the indexes that we find the window are from 109-118. And the corresponding weather delay (considering we could not find straight hours) is from index 101-108 (i.e. 9 hours.) I need to write a code for such an algorithm.

Some sample code that I could think of is as follows( though this is not exactly what I want):

```
window = 0;     % Initialize the counter for finding the weather window.
        for tt = step_index
            if Accessibility(tt) == 0
                % bad weather, move to next index
                % reset window.
                window = 0;
                k = k + 1;
                possible_window(k) = window;
                continue
            else
                % Increase window
                window = window + 1;
                % sote window history
                k = k + 1;
                possible_window (k) = window;
            end
        end
        tt = tt + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what output you're after but you can find a group of 10 or more `1`s quite easily using convolution:

```
w = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
n = 10;
find(conv(w, ones(1,n)) == n) - n + 1
```

this gives you the indices of where groups of 10 start

Comment: Note that solution could also be adjusted quite easily to find an arbitrary amound of ones in the block of 10. (by changing the `==n` into `>=8` for example).

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I'm not sure what you mean, the result of `conv` here can't be larger than `n`, and if you're looking for a smaller number, then wouldn't you rather set `n=8`?

Comment: I mean this solution also offers have the flexibility to find at least 8 good moments in a window of 10. -- The comment was mostly placed for the benefit of the asker.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin OK so you mean like 80% `1`s in window size of `10` in this case. I agree then.

Answer (score 2):

Let the data be

```
w = [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
step_index = 101;
step_duration = 10;
```

Then:

```
d = diff([0 w 0]);
starts = find(d==1); %// indices of starts of runs of 1's
ends = find(d==-1); %// indices of ends of runs of 1's (actually starts of 0's)
keep = find(ends-starts>=step_duration); %// detect runs that are long enough
starts = starts(keep)+step_index-1; %// keep only those runs and adjust with "-1"
ends = ends(keep)+step_index-2; %// "-2" because of how ends is defined
```

The result is in vectors `starts` and `ends`. In your example there is just one such window, so they contain just one element:

```
starts =
   109
ends =
   118
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on `strfind` to find starting indices of N or N+ consecutive ones  -

```
%// sample accessibility vector (different from the one in question) 
access_vec = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]

N = 10; %// N or N+ consecutive ones are to be detected
indices = strfind([0 access_vec],[0 ones(1,N)])
```

Output -

```
indices =
     1    13
```

---

Another example -

```
access_vec = [ 0 1 zeros(1,10) 1]
```

Output -

```
indices =
     []
```

Comment: I like the approach. But does it work? Try `a1 = [ 0 1 zeros(1,10) 1]`

Comment: Perhaps you need `t1 = [1 diff(a1==1) 0]`, if I try the testvector that @Dan used the current code comes up empty.

Comment: You may need to detect _changes_ in `a1`, rather than `1`'s in `a1`. I was writing my solution (now posted) based on that when I saw yours

Comment: @LuisMendo I figured I would use some other approach so that we don't end up with identical soluitions :)

Comment: I think you need to replace "`N-1`" by "`N`"

Comment: Another possibility: `regexp(char(access_vec+'0'), char(ones(1,N)+'0'), 'start')`

Comment: @LuisMendo You were right `N` should be there. I have a feeling we did come across a similar problem here and it could be a dup case. Seems like that regexp would work too, add that up to your solution? People might prefer shorter codes!

Comment: @Divakar I think it's more related to your string-like approach, so it belongs in this answer. Feel free to add it to your answer if you like!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a period with good weather, where this would be defined as having sufficient ones in a stretch of 10.

In that case you could use a filter to check how many ones occur in each stretch of 10. It could be something like this:

```
f= filter(ones(10,1),1,x)
```

Not sure about the syntax, but check it out. Filter should definitely get you there.

You could then follow up by finding good periods like so:

```
find(f==10)
find(f>=8)
find(f==max(f))
```